# MySQL Primary Key Field Type

Tags: mysql, types, primary-key, field

I am working with some transactional data and having issues with my primary key field.  When importing data from my order manager system and Google analytics, the OrderID field has the following two value formats:

```
123456  
002-0130775-1483424
```

How do I format this field to be a primary key?

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

(Running MySQL 5.5.27)

Comment: At worst, you could use `CHAR(20)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, keeping your primary key internal helps insulate you from change. Anything that could be exposed as data should be re-considered as a key.

Answer (score 3):

You should create an auto-increment primary key field that contains arbitrary integers (an 'internal' key)... you can put your actual "key" data in another field titled OrderNumber or something similar and put a unique index on it.

Answer (score 2):

As an option, you can set up a syntetic primary key (for your internal references only) and an indexed CHAR(20) column (probably with a unique index attached for consistency purposes) – this appears to be a better solution as one day you might want to integrate with another system which might have collisions with the existing data.

Comment: This worked!  Thank you :)  Decided to go this route besides others since to your point, original data is protected against future systems.  Not always about what you need today, but what you WILL need tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

See, primary key should be **bigint** in nature, However you can modify the way you want.
**MYSQL 5.5.27** have some  important changes from its earlier version ,please follow the link
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/news-5-5-27.html